# Get sub-key's count in admin list-filter

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"文章分类", default="")
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name=u"添加时间")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"文章分类"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category


class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=u"文章分类")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"文章题目", default="")
    content = UEditorField(width=1000, height=500,imagePath="media/", filePath="media/",verbose_name=u"文章内容")
    read_nums = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=u"阅读量")
    comment_nums = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=u"评论数")
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name=u"添加时间")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"文章"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now I need to show how many articles in category at django-admin page, in this page:
[image: I need to show]

How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom columns via the `list_display` of your admin class. There you can just add a method [that you add to your model (or the admin)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and that returns the desired value:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # ...
    def article_count(self):
        return self.article_set.count()
    article_count.short_description = 'Number of articles'  # displayed as label/column header


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['article_count']  # this is your custom method
    list_display = ['__str__', 'article_count', 'add_time']

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```